# Python 3 to_bytes function shows wrong leading zeros

Tags: python

I'm trying use the to_bytes function.

```
$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 0x007BEE82BDD9e866B2BD114780A47F2261C684E2.to_bytes(32,'big')
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00{\xee\x82\xbd\xd9\xe8f\xb2\xbd\x11G\x80\xa4\x7f"a\xc6\x84\xe2'
```

The 13 bytes of leading zeros are apparently wrong. Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

Your number is 20 bytes, and you requested 32. This gives you 12 extra `\x00`. The last one is the `00` in your number.